# Three-way interactions with two-way interactions consisting of only dummies :D

Tags: interaction, interpretation

In the following i am studying life expectancy as an example: where I have dummies for a person being male, female, smart, wealthy. The base reference is a child who is not smart or wealthy.

Life expectancy=β_1 Male+β_2 Female+β_3 Wealthy+β_4 Smart+β_5 (MALE Wealthy)+β_6 (FEMALE Wealthy)+β_7 (SMART Wealthy)+β_8 (MALE Wealthy)+β_9 (FEMALE Wealthy)+β_10 (MALE SMART Wealthy)+β_11 (FEMALE SMART Wealthy)

How should β_10 and β_11 be interpreted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In three-way ANOVA, how to interpret the three-way interaction?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245239/in-three-way-anova-how-to-interpret-the-three-way-interaction) As your three predictors are all categorical, your situation is the same as  a 3-way ANOVA. You might also look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47265/28500). In general, higher-level coefficients represent the expected _difference_ from what you might have predicted based only on the corresponding lower-level coefficients.